# Azure Powershell cmdlets - New-AzureWebsite : Requested value 'Premium' was not found

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

It gives me this kind of error, but site was created in Azure.

What I did in powershell:

```powershell
New-AzureWebsite somewebsite
```

Error message:

> New-AzureWebsite : Requested value 'Premium' was not found. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + New-AzureWebsite testscmpunetsu23
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureWebsite], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.NewAzureWebsiteCommand

Answer (score 1):

seems like the commandline and the output doesn't match as the output says testscmpunetsu23 .. I have tested this on latest powershell release 9.4 and see no issues, please provide the output of the command with -Debug option

Answer (score 1):

yes. I forgot to mask also output :)

my solution for this error was switch to Azure Resource Manager mode and after that it went well.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722470.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396